# Merge Content/DataTemplate for an object based on implemented interfaces in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to display an object in `XAML/WPF`. This object represents the progress status of an `async` operation, i.e. the T of `IProgress<T>;` as this can by any type, I can't make any assumptions about any shared base type or `interface`.

So the type can be pretty much anything. it can - but doesn't always! - implement one or more of the following interfaces:

```
public interface IHasStatusMessage
{
    string StatusMessage { get; }
}

public interface IHasCompletionAbsoluteNumbers
{
    int ItemsToComplete { get; }
    int ItemsCompleted { get; }
}

public interface IHasChildProgress
{
    object ChildProgressArgs { get; }
}
```

I want to display such an object inside a `WPF` element - namely a `BusyIndicator` from the extended `WPF` Toolkit.

It should be displayed like this (complete, ridiculous pseudo-code)

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">
  <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContent>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

        <If Object Is IHasCompletionAbsoluteNumbers>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemsCompleted"/>
          <TextBlock Text=" out of "/>
          <TextBlock Tet="{Binding ItemsToTemplete"/>
        </If>

        <If Object Is IHasStatusMessage>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusMessage}"/>
        <Else If Object Is Not IHasStatusMessage>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ToStringConverter}}"/>
        </If>

      </StackPanel>

      <If Object Is IHasChildProgress>
        <Apply the same template hierarchically to  ChildProgressArgs/>
      </If>
    </StackPanel> 
  </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContent>
</xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

Doing this in `Code` is super easy,

```
   public static UIElement ProgressToUIElement(object Progress)
    {
        var container = new StackPanel();
        container.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

        if (Progress == null)
            return container;

        var subCobtainer = new StackPanel();
        subCobtainer.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        if (Progress is IHasCompletionAbsoluteNumbers)
        {
            var CProgress = (IHasCompletionAbsoluteNumbers)Progress;

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = String.Format("[{0}/{1}] ", CProgress.ItemsCompleted, CProgress.ItemsToComplete);
            subCobtainer.Children.Add(tb);  subCobtainer.Children.Add(tb);
        }


        {
            IHasStatusMessage CProgress = Progress as IHasStatusMessage;
            string message = (CProgress != null) ? CProgress.StatusMessage : Progress.ToString();

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = CProgress.StatusMessage;
            subCobtainer.Children.Add(tb);
        }


        if (Progress is IHasChildProgress)
        {
            object child = ((IHasChildProgress)Progress).ChildProgressArgs;
            if (child != null)
            {
                var childUI = ProgressToUIElement(child);
                container.Children.Add(childUI);
            }
        }

        return container;
    }
```

But is it possible to replicate this behaviour in `XAML`? I.e. is it possible to turn my `XAML` pseudocode into actual `XAML` somehow? I'd be fine with having to involve some sort of code behind (converters, template selectors or you name it), but I don't feel too great about hard coding the entire layout as in my code solution above.

Appreciate any pointers and hints.